C#: Copy to output directory on Debug, but NOT Release
When building a C# project, is there a way to copy files to the output directory only with the Debug configuration, and not with the Release configuration?
Example problem I'm facing: I have two files, config.json and config.development.json. My application loads config.json if running in Release mode, and config.development.json in Debug mode (controlled using pre-processor directives). I don't particularly mind if config.json is included while compiling for Debug, but I want to avoid distributing config.development.json in Release, ideally in a cleaner way than deleting the file manually or automatically via CI/CD pipeline.
Looking at the "Properties" window in Visual Studio, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to copy files to the output directory exclusively on the Debug configuration. I would find instructions on how to ask Visual Studio to handle this acceptable, but IDE-agnostic solutions such as modifications to the .csproj file would likely be preferable to other readers.

Intsead of using the file properies, copy it via the Build Events (post-build). The events are not set per configuration (debug / release), but you can use a batch script that does. See here: How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only.

No need for build events. The ItemGroup element in csproj can have a condition. You can put different Content or CopyToOutputDirectory in different output groups with different conditions

You can edit your csproj file accordingly to conditionally copy. To that add an ItemGroup to your csproj like the below:
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <None Update="config.development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

Finally, your csproj would look like something below:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <None Update="config.development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="config.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

